# Webcam not working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, permissions, video, webcam, groups

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04, but the applications (Skype, Cheese) says no device found.

I have reviewed several topics on the subject, but none seem to work. 
Thank you!

**Edit:** In a beginning the output of `ls -l /dev/video0` is:

```
ls: Cannot access an '/dev/video0': file or directory does not exist.
```

Then when I put

```
sudo mknod /dev/video0 c 81 0
```

We have the output for `ls -l /dev/video0` is:

```
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 81, 1 Apr 19 22:25 /dev/video0
```

Output `getfacl /dev/video` and `ls -ltrh /dev/video*`

[image: Output 'getfacl /dev/video' and 'ls -ltrh /dev/video*']

Output `lsusb` and `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`

[image: Output 'lsusb' and 'v4l2-ctl --list-devices']

Output 'Cheese' by terminal. And when the camera is activated, it says: 'No device found'

[image: Output cheese by terminal]

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb` and `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`?

Comment: The groop `root` for your `/dev/video0` will deny access to the camera for users outside this group. Try running `sudo chown root:video /dev/video0` then run `sudo chmod 660 /dev/video0`. Also please avoid adding screenshots when you can copy and paste the output in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group and permissions for your `/dev/video0` are not correct. 
The groop `root` for your `/dev/video0` will deny access to the camera for users outside this group.

The output of `ls -l /dev/video0` should look like this:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Apr 19 22:25 /dev/video0
```

Try fixing the group by running:

```
sudo chown root:video /dev/video0
```

Then fix permissions by running:

```
sudo chmod 660 /dev/video0
```

Comment: @J.PabloCN no spaces .... like this `/dev/video0` NOT like this `/ dev / video0`

Comment: @J.PabloCN also no spaces in this `root:video` NOT like this `root: video`

Comment: @J.PabloCN Spaces are: `sudo` then space `chown` then space `root:video` then space `/dev/video0`  then press Enter

Comment: OK! thank you very much. Now the light on the camera built into the notebook turns on. But still the Cheese app, can't find any device.

Comment: @J.PabloCN Did you run `sudo chmod 660 /dev/video0` as well?

Comment: I edit the question. I forgot to mention that initially the directory 'dev/video0' doesn't exist, but when I put 'sudo mknod /dev/video c 81 0' it started to work.

Comment: @J.PabloCN `/dev/video0` is not a directory it is a node ie. a file descriptor and can be referred to as a file. So you fixed your cam?

Comment: nop. I have windows10/Ubuntu installed, and the windows camera also has an error and does not work. Maybe the problem is some bad installation

Comment: @J.PabloCN Windows has its own settings that are not affected by what you do in Ubuntu. This sounds like a hardware issue or BIOS settings issue if it affects both operating systems.